# jQuery - global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use variable in different function, I want to set *global* variable. Is there way how to do it?

I want something like this:

```
$('.bar1').animate({'height':'10' + "%"},1500, function() {  
    var bar1_height = $(".bar1").height() * 0.5;  
});
```

and then use variable `bar1_height` elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare `bar_height` outside of your function.

```
var bar1_height;
$('.bar1').animate({'height':'10' + "%"},1500, function() {
    bar1_height = $(".bar1").height() * 0.5;
});
```

This will allow you to access it globally (i.e. both inside and outside of your function).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variable_scope):

> When you declare a variable outside of any function, it is called a
>   global variable, because it is available to any other code in the
>   current document. When you declare a variable within a function, it is
>   called a local variable, because it is available only within that
>   function.

Comment: I have tried it to retrieve value `$('.test').text(bar12_height);` and it gave me "undefined%"

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the relevant code I can't help. Also, do you mean bar1_height or bar12_height?

Comment: this is a rest of the code, and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong   http://jsfiddle.net/lipcikm/zXJry/2/

Comment: Two things. 1) you should remove the var from `var bar1_height` within your animate call as that would essentially re-declare it. 2) Your code for assigning the value is right, but it's being executed before the animation is done. Move it inside like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zXJry/3/

Comment: Ok, but I want to use that variable bar1_height out side of the function ... I would like to use that value late in code, do you understand what I mean?

Comment: You can. By declaring it outside the function you have access to it throughout your code. However in order for it to have a value, in your case you need to wait until the animation is done.

Comment: Can you show  me example on my jsfindle? I have been trying to do it but without luck

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.bar1').animate({'height':'10' + "%"},1500, function() {  
    window.bar1_height = $(".bar1").height() * 0.5;  
});
```

Done.

Or a more ideal way to do

```
var bar1_height;
$('.bar1').animate({'height':'10' + "%"},1500, function() {  
    bar1_height = $(".bar1").height() * 0.5;  
});
```

Comment: While this is indeed a *global* variable (well, property really), it is also generally *not* an ideal way to solve this problem...

Comment: @pst - I know, but the OP says he wants a *global* variable, and this sure is global.

Comment: The OP is also less experienced with JavaScript. Provide additional information useful to make informed decisions :)

Comment: Upvoted, although explaining the differences would make this a better answer. Also, see RichardTowers answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the *worst* aspects of javascript is [implied global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909578/what-are-some-of-the-problems-of-implied-global-variables). You could make your variable global just by dropping the `var` keyword:

```
$('.bar1').animate({'height':'10' + "%"},1500, function() {  
   bar1_height = $(".bar1").height() * 0.5;  
});
```

But this is considered [very](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html) [bad](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations) [practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors). For example:

```
var getAddress = function(street, city, country) {
    location = street + ', ' + city + ', ' + country;
    return location;
}
getAddress('Holborn', 'London', 'England');
```

Can you spot the horrendous bug? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/HztV8/).

You should really declare your variable in the narrowest scope possible, otherwise you'll end up with a confusing mess of global variables. If you need a variable both inside and outside a function, you should simply declare it in the outer scope (as the other answers have said):

```
(function () {
    var bar1_height;

    $('.bar1').animate({'height':'10' + "%"},1500, function() {
        // Use variable from outer scope  
        bar1_height = $(".bar1").height() * 0.5; 
    }); 

    // Variable still has its value here
    alert(bar1_height);
})();
```

(The mysterious outer function here is to *prevent* the variable from being truly global.)

I found [this blog post](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/) very useful in understanding best practices regarding variable scope.